# What other ways are there to remove widgets from kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to make a word game that initially, it has a label and a textinput, after keying input into the textinput and hit enter, i want it to remove the that textinput widget and add 2 things (1) Label with the text (2) A new textinput widget. 
I have been trying to think what should i put for the callback function (fix_it) as the only way i know to remove widgets is by their names i.e. self.layout.remove_widget(self.new_inp), this will remove any subsequent textinput widgets, which i would not be able to see any textinput widgets.

I would appreciate any help from this community. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are asking, but the `inp` argument of your `fix_it` method is the `TextInput` instance. So you can remove it with `self.layout.remove_widget(inp)`.